# How to null terminate pointer passed as an argument

Tags: c++, c, pointers

So i have this function that reads file, allocates memory, and puts file's content into buffer. I constantly get garbage data in the end though, so i need a way to null terminate the buffer.

```
#include "GetText.h"

void GetText(const char* filename, char** buffer)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(filename,"rb");
    long file_lenght;

    if(file)
    {
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        file_lenght = ftell(file);
        rewind(file);

        *buffer = (char*) malloc(file_lenght + 1);

        fread(*buffer, 1, file_lenght, file);

        *buffer[file_lenght] = '\0'; //This line crashed program

        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `(*buffer)[file_lenght] = '\0';`.

Comment: The code would be much easier to understand (and to write) if you **returned** a pointer `char* GetText(const char* filename) { buffer = (char*) malloc(file_lenght + 1); ... return buffer; }` No double pointers needed.

Comment: And would be even easier if you used C++ style code instead of C style code `std::string GetText(...) { ... }` Using `std::string` will do all the hard work for you, especially the work of correctly freeing the allocated memory.

Comment: Or try `*(buffer + file_length) = '\0'`

Comment: Finally this is `C++` or `C` ?

Comment: @ssd Thank you, it works, but what did this magic brackets do?

Comment: @XenosEitan : August Karlstrom's answer has explanation.

Comment: @XenosEitan: In general, the expression `buffer[i]` is equivalent to the expression `*(buffer + i)`. In order to understand this, you should read more about pointers, for example in [this pointer tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm). You should especially read the part about "pointer arithmetic".

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel: Thanks, i'll check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the bracket operator has higher precedence than pointer dereference  you need to dereference *buffer* before indexing, like this:

```
(*buffer)[file_lenght] = '\0';
```

In your program you also need to make sure *malloc* was successful.